# Mails are sent to users when the payment transaction fails

Tags: emails

If the payment fails, for example because the bank account has an insufficient balance or an incorrect password is entered, the e-mails are sent to the users. After the payment method completes, it is redirecting to the "Complete" Page with the "Transaction has been declined" message.

How can I restrict the e-mails sent to users?

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict"? Mailing users about both success and failed transactions, as your site is doing now, is good. I fail to see what you want to know here.

Comment: In Checkout settings -> Checkout rules -> Notification Email -> I added another action -> Send Mail and passed parameter of Billing information email field. If payment is failed, then also it is sending mail. i.e., product details are sending to users as they purchased.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of commenting, with data like this.

Comment: Ya.. I redirected to another page for failed transactions in "payment method module" page. It is fine now. Thanks for your replies.